Sequence converging to different infinities
If we have a sequence  $a_{n}$ that looks something like $0$ if $n$ is odd and $1$ if $n$ is even, $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ doesn't exist and we therefore say that it diverges.
What if we have a similar definition of $a_{n}$, like
$$
a_{n} = n^{2}\ \mbox{for}\ n\ odd\quad\mbox{and}
\quad a_{n} = \exp\left(\,n\,\right)\ \mbox{for}\ n\ even
$$
In this case $\lim_{n \to \infty} = \infty$, but they are however different infinities. Is this still divergent ?.

what's the definition of a divergent sequence?

How exactly are they different infinities?

Same infinity, unless you are doing Nonstandard Analysis.

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$ is a notation that means for all $M$ there is $N$ such that $a_n\geq M$ for $n\geq N$. The $a_n$ doesn't converge at all, although it might be said that $a_n$ converges in some space larger than $\mathbb{R}$. For example the extended real line $\mathbb{R}\cup {\infty, -\infty}$, and then divergence to $\infty$ means literal convergence to an element $\infty$. There is no two such elements, just one

I think the confusion may arise from interpreting $(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty)$ as "$a_n$ converges to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$".
Generally speaking, if you have a sequence $a_n$ which converges to some limit for $n$ odd and the same limit for $n$ even then yes, the sequence $a_n$ also converges to that shared limit.
However, $(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty)$ should instead be read as "$a_n$ diverges to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$".
And hence why merging the two sequences as you described also results in a divergent sequence (regardless of whether the infinites are the same).

And how exactly is interpreting it like "$a_n$ converges to $\infty$" wrong or confusing?

Could you explain what you mean by "$a_n$ converges to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$"? I assume OP is using this definition of convergence: $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \left(\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \left(n \geq N \implies |x_n - x| < \varepsilon \right)\right)\right)$

If you work in the real line alone, then indeed in $\mathbb{R}$ there's no such thing as convergence to $\infty$, since $\infty$ is not a real number, although you can say it converges to $\infty$ on the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Hence I would say that it is confusing precisely because it doesn’t apply to $\mathbb{R}$. As soon as we extend the definition of convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ to include some notion of infinity, we have to concern ourselves with questions like “how many infinities are there?”, “are all infinities the same?”, “do the standard properties of limits still apply?”. The answers to those depend on our choice of extension and so suddenly OP’s questions becomes much more complicated.

It's still divergent and there's no canonical order of divergences so there's no way to rank the different ways in which a sequence can diverge; you can still claim validly that it diverges at different rates, and compare those rates, but you can't catalogue all the rates at which a sequence can diverge.

To be a bit more precise, different subsequences of a sequence can diverge at different rates.
